# Unable to pass json row in dynamically created table using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm creating a table dynamically using Angular JS. In my table, I have to pass JSON row. But when it renders it's showing error !

**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object] | QcDetailsManualAuto] starting at [Object] | QcDetailsManualAuto].**

CODE :

```
var jData = JSON.parse(response.data);
             var vQCTableData = jData.ResultData;
            var vQCTable = '';
            vQCTable += "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\" id=\"qctable\">";
            vQCTable += "<thead>";
            vQCTable += "<tr>";
            vQCTable += "<th>SOM</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>EOM</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>Type of Error</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>QC Type</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>Remarks</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>Action</th>";
            vQCTable += "</tr>";
            vQCTable += "</thead>";
            for(var td in vQCTableData)
            {                                                                                          
                vQCTable += "<tbody>";
                vQCTable += "<tr class=\"wer1\" ng-if=\"" + vQCTableData[td] + " | QcDetailsManualAuto\">";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +vQCTableData[td].SOM+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +vQCTableData[td].EOM+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +vQCTableData[td].Parameter+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +vQCTableData[td].QCType+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +vQCTableData[td].Remarks+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "<td class=\"MediaDataListPointer\">";
                vQCTable += "<span ng-click=\"QCParameterEdit(" + vQCTableData[td] + ")\" title=\"Edit\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil QualityCheckIcons\"></span>";
                vQCTable += "<span ng-click=\"DeleteMQC(" + vQCTableData[td] + ")\" title=\"Delete\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash QualityCheckIcons\"></span>";
                vQCTable += "</td>";
                vQCTable += "</tr>";
                vQCTable += " </tbody>";
            }
            vQCTable += "</table>";

            var mediadiv = angular.element(document.querySelector('#mediadiv'));
            mediadiv.html($compile(vQCTable)($scope));
```

In **[response]** I m getting data after calling URL.

**QCParameterEdit** function require json row for its functionality

```
    $scope.QCParameterEdit = function (data) {
    $("#GenerateMarksModal").modal();
    $scope.QCPDRButton = "Update";
    $scope.somModel = data.SOM;
    $scope.eomModel = data.EOM;
    $scope.qCParameterModel = data.QcParamUID;
    $scope.typeOfErrorModel = data.Type;
    $scope.typeModel = data.Type;
    $scope.remarksModel = data.Remarks;
    $scope.UID = data.UID;
    $scope.QcParameterIUDSuccess = false;
    $scope.QcParameterIUDFailure = false;
    $scope.QcParameterIUDSMessage = '';
    $scope.QcParameterIUDFMessage = '';
};
```

**QcDetailsManualAuto** is angular custom filter [Can not change it because it being used at multiple places]

```
app.filter('QcDetailsManualAuto', function () {
return function (value) {
    var result = false;
    if (value.QCType == 'Auto' || value.QCType == 'Manual') { result = true; }
    return result;
};
});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you show what you getting in `response`

Comment: {data: "{"ResultData":[{"UID":"d465703c-504c-4a4f-b8e2-287…MAMUID":"b435fc76-d44f-4210-b9e4-7792dc7a3934"}]}", status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}

Comment: data
:
"{"ResultData":[{"UID":"d465703c-504c-4a4f-b8e2-2877b0eadc12","SOM":"00:00:12:02","EOM":"00:00:14:24","Duration":"00:02:22","SegmentNo":"0","Remarks":"AN","Value":"0","IsActive":true,"QcParamUID":"99","Parameter":"Video Jerk","Type":"Video","QCType":"Manual","QCParameter_Remarks":"","QCParameter_IsActive":true,"UserID":"1","Username":"star","MAMUID":"b435fc76-d44f-4210-b9e4-7792dc7a3934"}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this :

```
var vQCT ='';
vQCT +="<table >";
                            vQCT +="<thead>";
                                vQCT +="<tr >";
                                    vQCT +="<th>SOM</th>";
                                    vQCT +="<th>EOM</th>";
                                    vQCT +="<th>Type of Error</th>";
                                    vQCT +="<th>QC Type</th>";
                                    vQCT +="<th>Remarks</th>";
                                    vQCT +="<th>Action</th>";
                                vQCT +="</tr>";
                            vQCT +="</thead>";
vQCT +="<tbody>";
                                vQCT +="<tr ng-repeat=\"QCTD in vQCTableData\" ng-if=\"QCTD | QcDetailsManualAuto\">";
                                        vQCT +="<td>{{QCTD.SOM}}</td>";
                                        vQCT +="<td>{{QCTD.EOM}}</td>";
                                        vQCT +="<td>{{QCTD.Parameter}}</td>";
                                        vQCT +="<td>{{QCTD.QCType}}</td>";
                                        vQCT +="<td>{{QCTD.Remarks}}</td>";
                                        vQCT +="<td>";
                                        vQCT +="<span ng-click=\"QCParameterEdit(QCTD)\" title=\"Edit\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil QualityCheckIcons\"></span>";
                                        vQCT +="<span ng-click=\"DeleteMQC(QCTD.UID)\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash QualityCheckIcons deleteQC\"></span>";
                                        vQCT +="</td>";                                
                                vQCT +="</tr>";
                            vQCT +="</tbody>";
                        vQCT +="</table>";

var mediadiv = angular.element(document.querySelector('#mediadiv'));
        mediadiv.html($compile(vQCT)($scope));

var jData = JSON.parse(response.data);
         $scope.vQCTableData= jData.ResultData;
```

in your response section

Comment: Thanx , this is answer as i require

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filter in controller instead of html something like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $compile,$filter) {
var data=[
    {
        "UID": "d465703c-504c-4a4f-b8e2-2877b0eadc1",
        "QCType": "Manual"
    }
]

var vQCTable = '';
            vQCTable += "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\" id=\"qctable\">";
            vQCTable += "<thead>";
            vQCTable += "<tr>";
            vQCTable += "<th>SOM</th>";
            vQCTable += "<th>EOM</th>";
            vQCTable += "</tr>";
            vQCTable += "</thead>";
            for(var td in data)
            {           
                vQCTable += "<tbody>";
                //notice the line below
                vQCTable += "<tr class=\"wer1\" ng-if=\"" + $filter('QcDetailsManualAuto')(data[td]) + ">";
                vQCTable += "<td>" +data[td].QCType+ "</td>";
                vQCTable += "</tr>";
                vQCTable += " </tbody>";
            }
            vQCTable += "</table>";
           console.log("your html string"+vQCTable);
          })



myApp.filter('QcDetailsManualAuto', function () {
return function (value) {
    var result = false;
    if (value.QCType == 'Auto' || value.QCType == 'Manual') { result = true; }
    return result;
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Okay ! What if i have to pass data to angular function ?

Comment: QCParameterEdit ?

Comment: Just replace `vQCTable += "<tr class=\"wer1\" ng-if=\"" + vQCTableData[td] + " | QcDetailsManualAuto\">";` with `vQCTable += "<tr class=\"wer1\" ng-if=\"" + $filter('QcDetailsManualAuto')(vQCTableData[td]) + ">";` in your code

Comment: Okay i understand how to pass data to filter , but there is a function within the scope name **QCParameterEdit** described above in my code , how to i pass data to that function.

Comment: may i know why you are doing all this stuff in controller you can do it in html also

Comment: because i want table on request only because there are 1000 rows ,  and rows means 1000 tables.

Comment: I Know that method to do all this stuff in html , but i only want to append table with data on request only.

Comment: then what you can attach request.data to `$scope` when request is made

Comment: Can you give me an example ? on jsFiddle it will bw great help ! Thanks in advance

Comment: simple change `var vQCTableData = jData.ResultData;` to `$scope.data= jData.ResultData;` and remove other stuff